# delay scrape for few minutes in R for loop

Tags: r, xml, sleep, rcurl

I am trying to scrape a website and it doesn't allow me to scrape more than 9 pages, is there any way I can stop the loop after 9 pages and break for a minute or two and then restart scrape?

Here is the code:

```
 library(RCurl)
 library(stringr)
 library(XML)

    jt<- c()
for (i in 1:70){
   tryCatch({
    html<- getURL((url[[i]]), followlocation = TRUE)
    doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
    new <- xpathSApply(doc, "div/a", 
      xmlValue)
    jt[[i]] <- new},error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})}
```

Comment: Add the sys.sleep() function to the loop.  The function  will pause the script.

Comment: Can it pause after number of iterations instead of every iteration?

Comment: There are two quick things you can do to better resemble normal traffic when scraping: 1) Set headers to a very common browser (Chrome is fine). 2) Add a `Sys.sleep` call (>= 1 second, better if randomized) to **every** iteration of your for loop. You'll probably be slower but it'll probably allow you to go past the 9 pages limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `if(i %% 9 == 0) {Sys.sleep(60)}` it will pause for 60 seconds every 9 iterations. The `%%` operator returns the remainder from dividing `i` by 9, so if that is equal to 0 you've completed 9 iterations.